# list.append causing memory inefficiency

Tags: python-3.x, list, memory-management

Below is my function

```
def loadData(self,datasetName,target_indx=None):

    tokens =[]
    labels = []
    ids = []
    allLabels = set()
    with open(self.dirPathName+datasetName+".csv",mode="r",encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            id,t, l = self.processLine(line)
            tokens.append(t)
            labels.append(l)
            ids.append(id)
            allLabels = allLabels.union(set(l))
    labelsList = list(allLabels)
    labelsList.sort()
   # print ("getting targets")
    targets = self.getTargets(labelsList,labels)
    #print ("finished getting targets")
    docs = []
    #print "read: " + str(len(targets))
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        doc = self.make_document(ids[i],tokens[i],labels[i],targets[i],target_indx=target_indx)
        docs.append(doc)
    return docs
```

[Highlighted piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLs1W.png)

**The CSV file that the above code opens for processing is of 700MB. It contains about 130000 rows.**

My problem lies in the highlighted piece of code as shown in above image. The **len(tokens)** maximum value is 75000. So the for loop will execute that many times. Now the **self.make document** function will process certain code and then
the result will be appended to list called **docs** as shown in highlighted portion of the image. This is causing my memory to freeze.

**Here is the make_document code**

```
def make_document(self,docid, tokens, labels, target,target_indx=None):
        """Return Document object initialized with given token texts."""
        #Here tokens is tokenized version of each line of text. So for first line it is ['Angiosperm','is','a']
        #Here labels is labels assigned to that document i.e.['7','71']
        #target is of shape length of unique labels. In our case 37. It is a numpy array with all zeros except where '7' is located 
        #in the unique labelsdictionary and '71' is located in the unique labels dictionary


        #This gives data in the following format:- [Token('Angiosperm'),Token('is'),Token('a')]
        tokens = [Token(t) for t in tokens]
        # We don't have sentence splitting, but the data structure expects
        # Documents to contain Sentences which in turn contain Tokens.
        # Create a dummy sentence containing all document tokens to work
        # around this constraint.

        #Create a sentence object
        sentences = [Sentence(tokens=tokens)]
        #Create a document object
        doc =  Document(id=docid,target_idx=target_indx,target_str=str(labels), sentences=sentences)
        doc.set_target(target)
        return doc
```

This code as you can see  calls a Document class which then returns an object. The object snapshot is below:

[Document object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Psd9.png)

**I know that large memory doesn't matter if you write inefficient code and this is what has happened. Can someone suggest me something?**

Comment: What will happen with the list `docs`? Cannot be function `loadData()` generator and just `yield doc` ?

Comment: you mean I should create a data generator? For which function?

Comment: I mean don't store objects created in `make_document()` inside list but `yield` them to whomever consumes them.

Comment: could you suggest me a code sample  based on my code? I don't exactly follow ...

Comment: Remove `return docs` and replace `docs.append(doc)` with `yield doc` inside `loadData()`

Comment: Oh..but I have to return list of doc to the returning function. So I need to have a list. That's why I appended all the doc values to a list...

Comment: That's why I asked in the first question, what happens with the list`docs`? It's just written to disk, for example? You could refactor your code, that the function that needs that list will now work with generator...

Comment: Sorry...I didn't followed it first time....I will try to do as per your suggestion...